# Light box hover do not work properly

Tags: html, css

Hello i made inline block list and wanted to made light hover around images. It works but not as i wanted, because light is around half of the image and it dont look nice. Maybe someone can tell me what i do wrong with my CSS and HTML and how can i make that light box go around my image?

```css
#planet {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 350px;
   margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
   position: relative;
   width: 679px; 
}

.planet2 {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align:center;
   margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.planet2 .img_img{
   width: 220px;
   text-align:center;
   height: 130px;
   -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
   transition: width 2s;
}

.planet2:hover > .ahove{
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
}


.planet2 .img_description {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="planet" style="background-image:url(../game/styles/images/port/rsz_senat_eo2.jpg)">
 
 <div class="planet2">
  <a class="ahove" href="">
   <img class="img_img" src="../game/styles/images/port/rsz_achiev_b.jpg"/> 
   <p class="img_description">Achievements</p>
  </a>
 </div> 
</div>
```

In here my light hover looks different, it goes around in the bottom of image, but in my page it goes in left side half till images middle and then line goes to middle of images bottom.

Comment: `a` is inline by default, so it doesn't span around the whole content when you drop block or inline-block stuff into it. All you need to do is make that `a` element itself either block or inline-block as well. (If you wanted the effect to include the paragraph, otherwise just apply it to the image only to begin with.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `.planet2:hover > .ahove` to `.planet2:hover > .ahove img`, and that'll do the trick.

```css
#planet {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 679px;

}



.planet2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.planet2 .img_img{
  width: 220px;
  text-align:center;
  height: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;

}


.planet2:hover > .ahove img{
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);

}


.planet2 .img_description {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="planet" style="background-image:url(../game/styles/images/port/rsz_senat_eo2.jpg)">

  <div class="planet2">
    <a class="ahove" href="">
      <img class="img_img" src="../game/styles/images/port/rsz_achiev_b.jpg"/> 
      <p class="img_description">Achievements</p>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this also

#planet {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 350px;
   margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    position: relative;
    width: 679px;

}



.planet2 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.planet2 .img_img{
    width: 220px;
    text-align:center;
    height: 130px;
     -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;

}


.img_img:hover{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.67);

}


.planet2 .img_description {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}


<div id="planet" style="background-image:url(../game/styles/images/port/rsz_senat_eo2.jpg)">

<div class="planet2">
            <a class="ahove" href="">
            <img class="img_img" src="../game/styles/images/port/rsz_achiev_b.jpg"/> 
        <p class="img_description">Achievements</p>
        </a>
        </div>

    </div>
```